# Filtros global em Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

Gostaria que todos os meus `DbSet` fizesse um filtro em todas as chamadas

Ou seja, gostaria que todos os `DbSet` fizessem o seguinte filtro:

```
Where(x => x.active == true)
```

Sem a necessidade de toda hora eu ter que fazer `dbo.Models.Where(x => x`

Como poderia criar algo assim, sem utilizar `respository pattern` ?

Comment: poderia dá um exemplo?

Comment: @TobyMosque Editei

Comment: não estou podendo formular uma resposta agora, mas você pode olhar o seguinte artigo: http://www.agile-code.com/blog/entity-framework-code-first-applying-global-filters/

Comment: @TobyMosque cheguei a olhar esse link...mas achei que haveria forma mais fácil, além de sobreescrever tudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um método de extensão, por exemplo:

```cs
public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions 
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Ativos<T>(this IDbSet<T> dados) 
    {
        return dados.Where(x => x.active == true).ToList();
    }
}
```

Uso:

```cs
meuDbSet.Ativos().Where( ... ).ToList();
```

Outra alternativa é definir uma propriedade no seu contexto não-mapeada e fazer o acesso apenas por ela:

```cs
public partial class MeuContexto: DbContext
{
    public MeuContexto()
        : base("name=ConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Modelo> ModelosSet { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Modelo> Modelos
    {
        get
        {
            return ModelosSet.Where(a => a.active);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Pacotes

Há ainda a opção de pacotes NuGet:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Filters/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/

Comment: Aí se eu tenho 1000 models, tenho que fazer 1000 métodos ? LOL

Comment: @Rod Veja o link do @TobyMosque. Tem uma implementação genérica bem legal lá. Dá pra melhorar o método de extensão, aliás, mas usaria `Expression`s e é bem complicado de escrever.

Comment: uma pena o EF não ter isso nativo =( , eu vi uma lib no nuget chamada EntityFramework.Filters

Comment: usei o EntityFramework.Filters, na verdade usei os 2 que você citou, preferi o Filters por parecer mais "maduro" e o cara que mantém mais ativo na comunidade